# TypeError app.use() requires middleware functions

Tags: node.js, express, expressions

Код ниже, не могу понять чего выдает эту ошибку?

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import session from 'express-sessions';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import config from './config/index';

const app = express();

app.listen(config.port, err => {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(`App live on port ${config.port}`)
});

app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: config.secret
}));

app.get("*", async(req, res) => {
  res.end('Hello')
});
```

Error log

```
TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
    at EventEmitter.use (/home/maks/DOIT/mean-app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:210:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/maks/DOIT/mean-app/server.js:14:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (/home/maks/DOIT/mean-app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/maks/DOIT/mean-app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/maks/DOIT/mean-app/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:154:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

Comment: На какую строчку жалуется node.js?

Comment: попробуйте код в привильном порядке написать. app.listen в конец

Comment: @DmitriySimushev на строку 210 в либе, на экспресс. Вся проблема в express-sessions. Почему-то считает что там нет параметров.

Comment: Приведите стектрейс из сообщения об ошибке

Comment: @DmitriySimushev добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в неправильно устновленых зависимостях и в подключении файлов.
Переустановил express и express-session с флагом --save, а так же использовал require.
Пример работающего кода:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const config = require('./config/index');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: config.secret
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get("*", async(req, res) => {
  path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')
});

app.listen(config.port, err => {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(`App live on port ${config.port}`)
});
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/185645)

Comment: @aleks.andr я исправил ошибку и код заработал. Ответ который я дал испервыющий? Или стоит дополнить?